# How to make a single line in different size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this sample data:

```
head(output.melt,10)
   month variable     value LineSize
1     01     1997 100.00000        1
2     02     1997  91.84783        1
3     03     1998  92.67626        1
4     04     1998 105.70113        1
5     05     1998 115.12516        1
6     06     1998 118.95298        1
7     07     1999 117.99673        1
8     08     1999 125.50852        1
9     09     1999 119.39502        1
10    10     1999 100.79032        1
11    03     Mean 103.17473        2
12    04     Mean 108.12440        2
13    05     Mean 109.54016        2
14    06     Mean 107.71431        2
15    07     Mean 107.86694        2
16    08     Mean 108.32371        2
17    09     Mean 102.06684        2
18    10     Mean  99.96975        2
19    11     Mean 111.94529        2
20    12     Mean 113.49491        2
```

I want to make a plot where one line has different `linetype` and `size`. I get the different `linetype` but not `size`:

```
theplot=ggplot(data = output.melt, aes(x=month, y=value,colour=variable,group=variable,linetype = LineSize)) 
    +geom_line()
    +scale_linetype( guide="none") 
    +ggtitle(as.character("Hello"))+theme_economist()
```

But the code above does not make the line (where `LineSize` is equal 2) wider then others, which I want. And adding `size=LineSize` to aes creates an ugly graph.
[image]

Comment: You are indeed specifying the linetype and not size `linetype = LineSize`. Try to replace that with `size = LineSize`

Comment: @C.Square Not working very well. `Warning message:
Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.`

Comment: I think you should put `geom_line( size = LineSize)`

Comment: @Aneconomist I then get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Comment: Why is LineSize a factor variable? Anyway, use size = as.numeric(LineSize) in the aes mapping.

Comment: @Roland Please post an answer because now I get ugly graphs only with your solution :/

Comment: I'm on my phone and can't run R code right now.

Answer (score 2):

As it was suggested in the comments you have to use following code:

```
theplot=ggplot(data = output.melt, aes(x=month, y=value,colour=variable,group=variable, size= as.numeric(LineSize))) 
    +geom_line()
    +scale_linetype( guide="none") 
    +ggtitle(as.character("Hello"))
```

Keep in mind that size of a `size = 2` is quite a lot so you would have to adjust your table.

Comment: This works better: `theplot=ggplot(data = output.melt, aes(x=month, y=value,colour=variable,group=variable,size=LineSize)) +geom_line(aes(linetype=LineSize))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(3, 1),guide="none")+ggtitle(as.character(names("Hello")))
`